# java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError while running roboelectric test cases on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, robolectric

I have test cases written with help of Roboelectric framework 3.2.2 .
When running on local system, i am able to run all the test cases but while running same on Jenkins server for coverage report , it gives below error:

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.robolectric.annotation.Config.application()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:612)
```

I have already tried deleting `.Gradle` folder from Jenkins but still same error.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!